# JQuery autocomplete event at a new value

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following code:

```
container.autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url: HOST + "/lib/gets/getjsonclients.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        ajaxCache[cachedTerm] = data;
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
            this.close
        },

        //change: function(event, ui) {
        //   alert($(this).val());
        //}, 

        open: function() {
        },

        close: function() {
        }
 });
```

I want to catch the enter key event when I type a new value (other that which I already have in my select list).

I have tried using the .result event but I have an error: *Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'result'* using the code:

```
    container.result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

The change: event is working OK but is fired only after I loose the focus on autocomplete and I need it to be done when I hit the enter key

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this solution.
However if there is a way to cancel the effect of one event while one was fired, and the activate again the event, please let me know.

```
  var oneEventFired = false;
  container.autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url: HOST + "/lib/gets/getjsonclients.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        ajaxCache[cachedTerm] = data;
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            oneEventFired = true;
            alert(ui.item.value);
            this.close
        },    
        open: function() {
        },    
        close: function() {
        }
 })
 .keypress(function(e) {
        if (!oneEventFired) {
            // activate when the enter key is hit
            if (e.keyCode === 13) 
            {
                alert("key" + $(this).val());
            }
        } else {
            oneEventFired = false;
        }
 });
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should bind container to keypress and catch the enter key (not tested but should work):

```
$(container).keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        $(this).autocomplete('search');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, is OK now but the problem is now that when I hit enter the key on one of the values from the select list the event select is fired and then also the keypress event is fired. In this case I want only one of them to be fired. Do you have any idea how can I stop one of them? Or may be I can use a local variable to verify this.

Comment: add after `.autocomplete('search')` : `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I have tried as you said and is not working... I have read about stopPropagation() that the method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. However I use the same container for autocomplete and keypress like this: <input id="autocomplete" />. The question is how can I stop to fire one event after another from the same container, not child or parent html tags.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this: you should try to rewrite your js taking into account that need (ie. change the way you attach the handler). May be you can try to track if the `source` function was called while pressing the enter key (use a `var enterKey = false`, set it to true inside keypress handler, check for true inside source function and finally, at the end of source function, set it to false.